# Como formatar o numero no php retirando as frações

Tags: php

Galera abaixo coloquei o código só para compreensão do que eu quero

Quero o seguinte que o valor `27.588877333333` imprima apenas `27` removendo os demais números como poderia fazer isso com `php`

```
<?php
    $numero = 27.588877333333;
    echo number_format($numero, 0, '', '');
?>
```

Comment: $numero = 27.588877333333;  $partes = explode(".", $numero); echo $partes[0];

Comment: Rapaz vc na frente sempre igual a SKY kkk obrigado amigão

Comment: Obrigado mano deu certo !

Comment: echo floor(27.588877333333);  retorna 27

Comment: round() - Arredonda um número para cima ou para baixo.  ceil() - Arredonda frações para cima.  
echo floor(27.588877333333); arredonda para baixpo

Comment: Pois e vie isso mesmo round() ficou 28 mais valeu também ficou top !

Comment: pela escolha da resposta, sua pergunta não está correta. `Quero o seguinte que o valor 27.588877333333 imprima apenas 27` echo round(27.588877333333); dará 28

Comment: Veja funções matematicas PHP em http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.math.php

Answer (score 0):

Utilize a função [`ceil`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ceil.php):

```
<?php
    $numero = 27.588877333333;
    echo ceil($numero);
?>
```

Comment: Obrigado amigão  já deu certo aqui blz !